# How to create a Box<UnsafeCell<[T]>>

Tags: rust

The recommended way to create a regular boxed slice (i.e. `Box<[T]>`) seems to be to first create a `std::Vec<T>`, and use `.into_boxed_slice()`. However, nothing similar to this seems to work if I want the slice to be wrapped in UnsafeCell.

A solution with unsafe code is fine, but I'd really like to avoid having to manually manage the memory.

Comment: `Box<UnsafeCell<[T]>>` seems fairly implausible to me, because it can't be indexed - are you sure you don't want `Box<[UnsafeCell<T>]>` (which is indexable, and should be fairly easy to get)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only (not-unsafe) way to create a `Box<[T]>` is via [`Box::from`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#impl-From%3C%26%27_%20%5BT%5D%3E), given a `&[T]` as the parameter. This is because `[T]` is `?Sized` and can't be passed a parameter. This in turn effectively requires `T: Copy`, because `T` has to be copied from behind the reference into the new `Box`. But `UnsafeCell` is not `Copy`, regardless if `T` is. Discussion about making `UnsafeCell` `Copy` has been going on for years, yielding no final conclusion, due to safety concerns.

If you really, really want a `Box<UnsafeCell<[T]>>`, there are only two ways:

- Because `Box` and `UnsafeCell` are both [`CoerceUnsize`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.CoerceUnsized.html), and `[T; N]` is [`Unsize`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/trait.Unsize.html), you can create a `Box<UnsafeCell<[T; N]>>` and coerce it to a `Box<UnsafeCell<[T]>`. This limits you to initializing from fixed-sized arrays.

Unsize coercion:

```
fn main() {
    use std::cell::UnsafeCell;
    let x: [u8;3] = [1,2,3];
    let c: Box<UnsafeCell<[_]>> = Box::new(UnsafeCell::new(x));
}
```

- Because `UnsafeCell` is [`#[repr(transparent)]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html#the-transparent-representation), you can create a `Box<[T]>` and unsafely mutate it to a `Box<UnsafeCell<[T]>`, as the `UnsafeCell<[T]>` is guaranteed to have the same memory layout as a `[T]`, given that `[T]` doesn't use niche-values (even if `T` does).

Transmute:

```
// enclose the transmute in a function accepting and returning proper type-pairs
fn into_boxed_unsafecell<T>(inp: Box<[T]>) -> Box<UnsafeCell<[T]>> {
    unsafe {
        mem::transmute(inp)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = vec![1,2,3];
    let b = x.into_boxed_slice();
    let c: Box<UnsafeCell<[_]>> = into_boxed_unsafecell(b);
}
```

Having said all this: I strongly suggest you are suffering from the [xy-problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). A `Box<UnsafeCell<[T]>>` is a very strange type (especially compared to `UnsafeCell<Box<[T]>>`). You may want to give details on what you are trying to accomplish with such a type.

Comment: I'm trying to create an arena-allocator for slices, where I can also sneak in and do operations across everything in the arena. The `Box<UnsafeCell<[T]>>` would contain the backing memory. `UnsafeCell<Box<[T]>>` also works, I just found it harder to work with, since creating a pointer to the backing memory now requires unsafe code, and it also introduces a pointer-to-a-pointer situation.

Answer (score 2):

Just swap the pointer types to `UnsafeCell<Box<[T]>>`:

```rust
use std::cell::UnsafeCell;


fn main() {
    let mut res: UnsafeCell<Box<[u32]>> = UnsafeCell::new(vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5].into_boxed_slice());
    unsafe {
        println!("{}", (*res.get())[1]);
        res.get_mut()[1] = 10;
        println!("{}", (*res.get())[1]);    
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7900d17ec83895d3a96ac7b569a27541)

Comment: Using `get_mut()` here defeats the purpose of using `UnsafeCell` (the line should be `(*res.get())[1] = 10;`).